# pyodbc and sql server, apply datetime.date to DATE column

Tags: python, sql-server, freetds, python-datetime

pyodbc handles well datetime.datetime objects with DATETIME column. No special formatting needed.
But it fails with datetime.date objects and DATE column:`[HY004] [FreeTDS][SQL Server]Invalid data type (0) (SQLBindParameter)`

One way is to insert datetime.date object as string, with .isoformat() method.

But:

```
d1 = dt.date.today()
d2 = dt.datetime.now()
print(isinstance(d1, dt.date))
print(isinstance(d1, dt.datetime))
print(isinstance(d2, dt.date))
print(isinstance(d2, dt.datetime))
```

returns

```
True
False
True
True
```

isn't there a better way than testing like that?

```
if isinstance(d1, dt.date) and not isinstance(d1, dt.datetime):
    d1 = d1.isoformat()
```

Comment: Are you using `FreeTDS` to connect? What's your FreeTDS and unixODBC configuration? Or are you connecting from Windows? This may be caused by using too low a TDS Version.

Comment: *"But [pyodbc] fails with datetime.date objects and DATE column"* - This is a FreeTDS ODBC issue, not a pyodbc issue *per se*. pyodbc works fine with DATE columns and `datetime.date` parameter values when using Microsoft's "ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server".

Comment: yup FreeTDS indeed, I modify tags

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to reproduce your issue under FreeTDS 0.91, which is the version distributed by `apt install tdsodbc` under Ubuntu. However, I was able to successfully use a `datetime.date` parameter value to populate a DATE column using

- the latest stable version of FreeTDS (currently 01.00.0080), or
- Microsoft's "ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server"

Comment: I was indeed using 0.91 under Debian (ie should be same as your Ubuntu).ii    freetds-common                       0.91-6                      all          configuration files for FreeTDS SQL client libraries
ii  tdsodbc:amd64                        0.91-6+b1                   amd64        ODBC driver for connecting to MS SQL and Sybase SQL servers

Comment: Problem is even with Debian testing (aka Buster) only 0.91-6.1 is avail.

Comment: It should work if you set TDS Version to be 7.2 if your configuration with 0.91. If you have it set to 8.0 or 7.1 or less, it doesn’t support the DATE type.

Comment: @FlipperPA - I tried adding `;TDS_version=7.2` to my connection string under 0.91 but it didn't solve this particular problem (parameter binding). I also tried `;TDS_version=7.3` but apparently 0.91 does not support protocol version 7.3 because TDSDUMP told me that it was actually using protocol version 4.2 (the default).